# Part of mesh unselectable in vertex mode, still accessable in edge and face modes, but unable to be assigned to any vertex groups

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am in the process of rigging up a character only to be hit by this weirdness I havent encountered before.

The headband of the goggles (Shown below) is completely uninteractable when in vertex selection mode, though can be accessed via the edge and face modes. However, even when you do manage to get it selected, it is impossible to add to any vertex groups, making it unriggable. The statistics overlay also shows it as containing 0 vertexes.

Both the affected and uneffected parts are part of the same object and I've attempted saving and reloading, leaving and entering edit mode but to no avail.

At this point, I'm at a loss as to what caused this or how to remedy it besides replacing it completly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've added the link to the bottom of the post.

Comment: it works fine here, as soon as the file is opened, vertices are displayed, I can add vertices, edge loops, vertex group, etc

Comment: Been playing around my end, it seems separating the head out into the separate file that I shared temporarily fixed it. I was able to import it back in and manually added it to the group.

However, once I toggled weight paint mode on and off, it went back to being broken again. It kept hold of it's vertex groups and is now rigged up, but is back to being unselectable.

Comment: I've tested in 2.90.1, it worked bad once, then it worked normally...

Comment: Continued experimenting (removing all vertex groups, unparenting from the armature etc) but I've had no luck. At this point it may be easier to start just delete that part and redo it a bit tidyer and hopefully it won't break this time.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate the help.

Comment: maybe someone will find what's the problem  ;)

Comment: After some more experimentation, it seems to be related to joining 2 objects together. After joining two objects, all appears to be fine, until Weight Paint mode is toggled, at which point it becomes inaccesable.

It can be avoided by leaving them a separate objects.  

A few more details of note -

Even if selected in Face/Edge mode, anything affected is not able to be grabbed or otherwise transformed. Seemingly, deleting the faces seems to be the possible action.

The information in the Item panel shows that nothing is selected.

Comment: joining 2 objects together should not cause any problem, it may be a bug...